# stringWithContentsOfUrl in background

Tags: ios

UPDATE:  Here's all the file's I'm using in my github repo.  Perhaps it will help more than my code snippets:

[appDelegate](https://github.com/ImDevinC/iOSMyTLCSyncv2/blob/master/MyTLC%20Sync/mytlcAppDelegate.m)
[mainViewController](https://github.com/ImDevinC/iOSMyTLCSyncv2/blob/master/MyTLC%20Sync/mytlcMainViewController.m)
[calendarHandler](https://github.com/ImDevinC/iOSMyTLCSyncv2/blob/master/MyTLC%20Sync/mytlcCalendarHandler.m)

```
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

That's the line I'm using in my project to get data from a website.  I run this in an NSOperationQueue and when I run with my app in the foreground, it works without issue.  However I also have my app set to run in the background using performFetchWithCompletionHandler.  All of my setup code works fine using the performFetch, but when it hits the line I've outlined above, the app just hangs until I bring my app into the foreground again.
How can I let this work in the background?

In my AppDelegate I have performFetchWithCompletionHandler:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{    
 UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*) self.window.rootViewController;

id topViewController = navigationController.topViewController;

if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]])
{
    [(ViewController*)topViewController autoLogin];
}

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

My NSOperationQueue is built like this in my MainViewController:

```
- (void) autologin
{
NSOperationQueue* backgroundQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];

ch = [[myEventHandler alloc] init];

NSInvocationOperation* operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:ch selector:@selector(runEvents:) object:login];

[backgroundQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

And in MyEventHandler I have runEvents

```
 - (void) runEvents
{
     NSURL* urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

    NSError* err = nil;

    NSString* result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code you're using in the NSOperation.

Comment: Added, sorry about that!

Comment: Hmmm... I thought you would have more code in there, so that's not very helpful in diagnosing your problem. You probably need to post what you're doing in runEvents:, and (if this is a different place) where you call performFetchWithCompletionHandler

Comment: Sorry, didn't think setting the URL or my performFetch would have an effect.  Updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using NSURLConnection (asynchronous) instead of stringWithContentsOfURL (synchronous)?

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
NSString *theResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// blah blah
}];
```

Comment: I'm trying to not to perform this asynchronously as I have a lot of stuff I need to do with the data I receive (ie: parse it, and then send another request).  However, this method didn't solve the problem either.  I added links to my full code at the top of my post, maybe it will help more?

Answer (score 0):

Try with This code:

```
 NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@listcontact.php?uid=%@&page=0",LocalPath,appdel.strid];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
       NSError *error1;
     NSDictionary *res=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error1];
 }];
```

Comment: I'm trying to not to perform this asynchronously as I have a lot of stuff I need to do with the data I receive (ie: parse it, and then send another request).  However, this method didn't solve the problem either.  I added links to my full code at the top of my post, maybe it will help more?